# php script cache , cache also a admin content

Tags: php, mysql

i want increase the speed of my website build in php, i tested to use this script :

top page :

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'cached-'.substr_replace($file ,"",-4).'.html';
$cachetime = 18000;

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    include($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer
?>
```

bottom page :

```
<?php
// Cache the contents to a file
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
?>
```

now the script work fine ,but id you are logged in admin area, this script cache also a content that view only when you are logged.

now i want this script cache only when never user is logged.

in my site, the condition  if a user are registered or not is this:

```
    if($_info_["partner_loggato"] OR ($_info_["is_superadmin"] OR $_info_["is_admin_autorizzato"]))
```

now how work this script only when this user is not logged ?, and also this is a good method or it's possible use other alternative?

i have used this code example in the top but compare white page:

```
<?

    if($_info_["partner_loggato"] OR ($_info_["is_superadmin"] OR $_info_["is_admin_autorizzato"]))

                    {}
                      else
                      {

$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'cached-'.substr_replace($file ,"",-4).'.html';
$cachetime = 18000;

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    include($cachefile);
    exit;
}
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer



}

        ?>
```

Comment: I suppose your used not logged is if(!$_info_["partner_loggato"])

Comment: thanks  for answer , but not understand, can you clarify